# Ordering a feild (date) in simple Vega Data Table

Tags: kibana, vega, vega-lite

I have a simple text vega ata table which we use in Kibana, it works fine, but I'm trying to find a way to order the results based on the arrival date, code below:

```
   {

  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.json
  config: {
    title: {offset: 20, fontSize: 14, font: "Helvetica", anchor:"start"}
  }
  title: {
    text: Departure Airport    Arrival Time   
  }
  background: white
  width: 1200
  height: 100
  padding: {"left": 0, "top": 5, "right": 5, "bottom": 5}
  autosize: {type: "pad"}

  // Define the data source
    data: [
    {
      name: source
      url: {
        // change "index" to the name of the index
        index: myindex*
        "%context%": true 
        body: {
          size: "10"
        }
      }
      format: {property: "hits.hits"}
      transform: [
        {
          type: flatten
          // change fields to the actual path for flight segment but keep _source as a prefix
          fields: ["_source.Something.FlightSegment"] 
          as: ["val"]
        }
        {
          type: formula
          as: x_position
          expr: width * 1 / 4
        }
        {type: "formula", as: "line_height", expr: "20"}
        {
          type: stack
          groupby: ["x_position"]
          field: line_height
          as: ["y0", "y1"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  marks: [
    {
      type: text
      from: {data: "source"}
      interactive: true
      encode: {
        enter: {
          x: {field: "x_position", offset: -250}
          y: {field: "y0"}
          y2: {field: "y1"}
          align: {value: "right"}
          text: {field: "val.DepartureAirportCode"}
          font: {value: "Helvetica"}
          fontSize: {value: 14}
        }
      }
    }
    {
      type: text
      from: {data: "source"}
      interactive: true
      encode: {
        enter: {
          x: {field: "x_position", offset: -150}
          y: {field: "y0"}
          y2: {field: "y1"}
          align: {value: "left"}
          text: {field: "val.ArrivalDateTime"}
          font: {value: "Helvetica"}
          fontSize: {value: 14}
        }
      }
    }

  ]
}
```

This is the result here:

[image]

You can see that the results are returned, but are out of order. What I would like to do is order it by `ArrivalDateTime`.

My problem is that most tutorials I have seen are for actual graphs and not for just plain old text.

Really appreciate anyone helping me out here.

Comment: Please make is editable in https://vega.github.io/editor (all keys need quotes).

Comment: I answered your question but to validate that for sure please fix your json :)

Comment: @ClemensTolboom so in Kibana using Vega you don't actually use quotes like a normal JSON structure. It's weird I know, I don't know why it's setup this way. The query above works (apart from the sorting)

Comment: Was my answer useful? If so please mark it as the answer. Regarding kibana versus vega-list: if you want people to easily help making it vega compatible would help a lot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this too so found [Vega lite sort](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html)

Especially [sort by encoding from another field](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html#sort-by-encoding) will do the job.